# How to change Vertex Selection to Face Selection?

Tags: selection-tools

How to change any selection mode to a different mode? Vertex selection to face selection or edge, edge to face, etc.

Comment: on the top of the 3D view, the 3 icons, or shortcuts 1, 2 and 3

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts are going to depend on the initial interface choices you made when you ran Blender for the first time.  They also depend on what mode you're in-- changing to weight paint/vertex mode is different than changing to edit/vertex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the top of the 3D view, the 3 icons:

[image]

Or shortcuts 1, 2 and 3:

[image]

Comment: ..Taking  BSE answer illustration to a whole new level :D

Comment: I felt it was necessary as I don't know how these keys (not numpad numbers) are called  ^^

Comment: Nice idea :) Actually I don't know the name either. I usually expect that when someone says press 1 he means I shall press the "standard key", not the numpad key (or it doesn't make a difference, maybe in a different program than Blender). I think in keyboard layout the "normal" numbers belong to the _Typewriter keys_, but I never heard someone say something like this.

Comment: you're right, standard vs numpad is a good idea

Comment: +1 For the illustration. Isn't it just called *Number Row*?

Answer (score -1):

Hold SHIFT while hitting 1, 2 or 3.

For example, if you selected two faces, and want the 8 verts selected instead, hold Shift while those faces are selected and then hit '1.' Your face selection will change to vertex selection(s)

Comment: Why hold _Shift_? Just press 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: Holding Shift is used for combined selection mode where you can select two types of geometry like Vertex and Faces, or Edges and Faces at the same time

Comment: Right, I know this - but maybe not the OP and it's not stated in the answer, and since the question asked for switching modes, not combining them it is first of all more inefficient to hold Shift while pressing the number if the number would be sufficient and secondly (but of course that's a matter of taste) it can lead to errors sometimes if you accidentally select wrong things with more than one mode at once. Maybe no problem for experienced users, but this should be helpful for beginners as well.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear I was backing your comment, @GordonBrinkmann. I was just pointing out to FunkyKong that while this may be useful, it is not as far as I can tell what the OP asked about.